# Affine geometry

Tags: geometry

Let $A$ and $B$ be two affine spaces and $f:A\to B$. If:

(1) the image of lines are lines
(2) preserves parallelism

then $f$ is an affine map.

Where I can find the proof?

Comment: Over what field? Real numbers? Complex numbers?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ affine spaces over the $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces $V_A$ and $V_B$

Comment: Then check out "fundamental theorem of projective geometry".

Comment: What is your definition of an affine map? In some contexts, the properties you describe might be used as a definition. So you have to show *your* defining properties from the ones you listed. Do you have an algebraic definition (linear map plus offset), or some other axiomatic characterization?